# DIVs to randomly fadeIn on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay, I've seen a few things that *sort of* * answer my question, but none of them quite do what I want to do / I'd like to understand how to do this myself from start to finish as a learning exercise. I'm a novice at all this, so bear with me!

**What I'm Trying to Do:**
I have a black page and I'd like 20-30 small, white div boxes to fadeIn at random positions on the page (like stars is sort of the vibe I'm going for).

Ideally, they wouldn't overlap and they would be randomly sized between 5px and 10px, but I recognize that this might be getting a little too complicated.

**Here's what I have so far**

I've been working off [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/) and well as [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/). This is what I've come up with (that doesn't work, they all fade in equally spaced in a line and don't stay confined from to the site)

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/u1p95v6r/3/), code below

```
 function randomPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height()-10;
    var w = $(window).width()-10;

    var newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [newHeight, newWidth];
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var newPosition = randomPosition();
    $('.star').css( {
        'margin-left':newPosition[1]+'px',
        'margin-top':newPosition[0]+'px'
    }).each(function(index) { $(this).delay(1500*index).fadeIn('slow');
                            })
});
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

.star {
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
background-color: white;
display: none;
}
```

**HTML** (is there a way to do this with just a for loop or something similar?)

```
<div class="star"> </div>
<div class="star"> </div>
<div class="star"> </div>
<div class="star"></div>
```

Comment: you might also be interested in [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: You want them to fadeIn and stay there ... without fading out eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sizing and positioning isn't too hard. The thing is to do it all in the each loop - currently you get 1 position and use it for everything. Also you will want to make them `position:absolute` so they don't go off the page.

I've updated your fiddle to set the random position and a size between 5 and 10px:

The overlapping is a bit harder. You need to keep track of the sizes and positions you have generated and in the same `.each` function compare the current generated size+position to the previous ones to check for overlapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ocb5aww/3/

```
function randomPosition() {
    var h = $(window).height()-10;
    var w = $(window).width()-10;

    var newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [newHeight, newWidth];
}

function randomSize() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 5;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // stores generated star positions
    var stars = [];
    $('.star').each(function(index) {
        var newPosition, newSize;

        // check for overlap
        var isOverlap = true;
        while(isOverlap)
        {
            newPosition = randomPosition();
            newSize = randomSize();
            // check previous stars to see if an edge of this one overlaps
            isOverlap = $.grep(stars, function(s) {
                return (
                    (newPosition[1] >= s.x1 && newPosition[1] <= s.x2)
                    || (newPosition[1]+newSize >= s.x1 && newPosition[1]+newSize <= s.x2)
                    )
                  && (
                    (newPosition[0] >= s.y1 && newPosition[0] <= s.y2)
                    || (newPosition[0]+newSize >= s.y1 && newPosition[0]+newSize <= s.y2)
                    );
            }).length > 0;
        }

        // store to check later stars against it
        stars.push({
            x1: newPosition[1],
            x2: newPosition[1] + newSize,
            y1: newPosition[0],
            y2: newPosition[0] + newSize,
            size: newSize});

        $(this).css({
            'margin-left':newPosition[1]+'px',
            'margin-top':newPosition[0]+'px',
            'width':newSize + 'px',
            'height':newSize + 'px'
        });
        $(this).delay(800*index).fadeIn('slow');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to your exercise ... the overlapping position would require a little bit more effort ... I'll leave you that to sort for yourself (may require restructuring the code I'm handing here)

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/y2o68ho4/2/)**

JS

```
function starDust(wdt, hgt, tSt, tAp){
   var timer = tAp * 1000;
   var defInt = tSt,      
        starInt = setInterval(function(){
            var posX = Math.floor((Math.random() * wdt) + 1),
                posY = Math.floor((Math.random() * hgt) + 1),
                size = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

            $('body').append('<div class="star"></div>');
                        $('.star:last').css({'width':size,'height':size,'left':posX,'top':posY}).hide().fadeIn('slow');

     var totalStars = $('.star').length;

     if(totalStars == defInt){
     clearInterval(starInt);
     }

 }, timer);

}

$(function(){

    // Function arguments: starDust(max X position in px, max Y position in px, total number of stars, time in seconds between stars show);
    starDust(600,300,25,1);

});
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
}

.star{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    min-width:5px;
    min-height:5px;
}
```